# store cookies in electron application

Tags: angular, electron

I want to store cookies in electron application. I have written a query to set a cookie in my electron application, it is set and printing in the console, after opening my electron application it is not showing in cookie storage. And I don't know which URL to use to set the cookie.

I am using queries.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/cookies ? What does not work on the approach they describe

Comment: Can you post the code for your query, both when you save and load the cookie? If you use localStorage I think the data will dissapear when you build the application.